# Custom DisplayForm not linking to the Custom Content Type's Display Form

Tags: blog, visual-studio-2013, mysite, display-form, feature-stapling

I have a Content Type that has been stapled with a feature to `SPSERS#2` and `BLOG#0`.

The linkage does not work when i staple the feature to the `BlogSiteTemplate`. When i checked the content type in SharePoint Designer the Display Form link is empty.

It works fine the content type is usable and such.

Hence i created a custom display form. I have tested the form and the linking code to the content type to Portal and it works.

Below is the code used to link to Display Form for the custom content type

```
<XmlDocuments>
  <XmlDocument NamespaceURI="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms">
    <FormUrls xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms/url">
      <Display>_layouts/15/ListFormViewTest/DisplayForm.aspx</Display>
    </FormUrls>
  </XmlDocument>
</XmlDocuments>
```

It is placed after `</FieldRTefs>` and before `</ContentType>`
I have set the content type inherits value to **FALSE**.

I have tried deploy the feature itself to a personal MySite and the content type works fine with the linkage of the custom display form present.

Does anybody have this issue as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the answer to this...
It was a mistake on my part.
Notice the NamespaceURI and FormUrls

```
<XmlDocument NamespaceURI="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms">
    <FormUrls xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms/url">
```

The NamescapeURI was missing the /url in the http link.

After editing it from

```
NamespaceURI="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms">
```

to

```
NamespaceURI="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms/url">
```

Everything worked.